# My drop down menu works fine in jsFiddle but not when I test in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I've scoured through previous stack posts and tried every method I could find but alas, nothing has worked.

My drop down menu works fine in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JFQ8/5/

But when I preview the code with firefox or safari the drop down menu under the "services" link does not line up directly under the "services" link button and the drop down menu disappears when I try to move the mouse down.

BTW thank you to all who respond to these questions. This site has helped me out a bunch in the past, but unfortunately this is my first time posting.

Comment: Well, a working jsFiddle is nice, but I'm afraid it doesn't help solve your issue at all unless you can re-create the problem there. Can you post the code that's actually causing the problem, or a link to the real page? Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: FF 10.0 and it works fine for me.

Comment: Fiddle works fine for me in Chrome. Without seeing it in context with the rest of your code I'm not sure how much help we can give you. It all looks fine to me so I'd assume it's something in the rest of the page messing things up.

Comment: @Shoban - "My drop down menu works fine in jsfiddle"

Comment: Downvote for a perfectly reasonable 1st Q is a bit harsh.

Comment: I think I figure it out. I just added some px to the top of ul.dropdown ul. So this...  ul.dropdown ul{ top:5px} Is this a permanent fix though? Or is it just duct tape?

Comment: Not checked your answer but if it works it works. Sometimes finished is better than perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Shivaji 
This works in Firefox and Safari. 
I changed:

> > ul.dropdown ul { 
> >         width: 200px; 
> >         visibility: hidden; 
> >         position: absolute; 
> >         top:100%; 
> >         left:0;  }

to:

> ul.dropdown ul { left: 0; list-style: none outside none; padding: 0;
>   position: absolute; top: 5px; visibility: hidden; width: 200px; }

The "top:5px" made it possible to click the drop down menu. 
The "list-style: none outside none;
padding: 0; " fixed the alignment issue. 
Beware this hasn't been tested in Chrome or IE! Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
left: 0;
list-style: none outside none;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
visibility: hidden;
width: 200px;
}
```

Include `padding:0 & list-style:none`

Comment: Thanks @Shivaji! That fixed my alignment problem but I'm still having issues with the drop down menu disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
position:absolute;
```

in nav style like this maybe helpful

```
nav{
  margin-top:10px;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  clear:both;
  font-family:"Copperplate Gothic Light";
}
```